# Normal Equation and pinv() in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-inverse

I'm studing the fundamentals of Machine Learning and, when I was reading about the use of Normal Equation in Matlab, I had a question.

If the **Normal Equation** is:

[image]

And

[image]

Is the **Pseudo Inverse**, so:

[image]

And `pinv(X)`  compute the pseudo inverse of `X`.

Why, in Matlab/Octave, some people use:

```
theta = pinv(X'*X)*X'*y ...(4)
```

instead of

```
theta = pinv(X)*y ...(5)
```

?

Is (4) not redundant? doesn't `pinv(X)` compute the pseudo inverse formula for us?

Thank you!

Comment: (4) seems redundant, yes. Where have you seen this done? Perhaps whoever coded it like that was following a formula verbatim without making the mental connection like you did.

Comment: I suppose it may be worth pointing out that (2) would not apply for complex inputs (since the pseudoinverse is actually defined via the Hermitian transpose rather than a simple transpose), and therefore if (1) also applies for complex inputs (which is beyond my knowledge if it does), then you would be unable to use (5) when dealing with complex inputs, and you'd have to use (4) directly. But I would seriously doubt this was the reason for seeing (4) in the wild. It's probably just someone copying a formula verbatim into code.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, thank you for reply and sorry for my later reply. I had some preblems these previous days. I'm taking the Machine Learning course of Andrew Ng in Coursera. And in their examples he use the (4) code. Then, I have been looking for more examples in github and, the examples works, but I would like to know why not use the (5) code.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou. Yes, number (2) don't aply for complex inputs. I assuming that X matrix is full of real numbers. And yes, I think the same about copying the formula, but maybe there's an explanation, maybe.

Comment: Indeed, I'm curious now too! I know cross-posting is frowned upon in Stackoverflow, but if you removed the matlab programming specific elements of the question and stick to the maths, perhaps this independent question would be a better question for stats.stackexchange.com anyway. If you _do_ post such a question there, would you mind sharing the question link back here? :)

Comment: @Papastylianou. In fact, I haved asked to a matematician friend and he tell me that the matematic part of this post is okay, so I asked for the coding part. But yesterday I ask this question to a friend who use MATLAB for a long time, and he told me that the (4) equation is okay. Maybe, in the course use the (5) equation just for highlight the formula. Do you think it should be a good answer for this post and I would write it as the final answer? Or I should wait for a more thecnical answer?

Comment: As far as I am aware Octave's `pinv()` function works with a complex argument, at least it did when I tried it just now (version 6.4.0), so (5) should still give the same result as (4) when `X` is complex.